# How to write a PowerShell function to get directories?

Tags: powershell, directory, get-childitem

Using PowerShell I can get the directories with the following command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include "obj" -Recurse | `
    Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
```

I would prefer to write a function so the command is more readable. For example:

```
Get-Directories -Path "Projects" -Include "obj" -Recurse
```

And the following function does exactly that except for handling `-Recurse` elegantly:

```
Function Get-Directories([string] $path, [string] $include, [boolean] $recurse)
{
    if ($recurse)
    {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include $include -Recurse | `
            Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
    }
    else
    {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include $include | `
            Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
    }
}
```

How can I remove the `if` statement from my Get-Directories function or is this a better way to do it?

Comment: Consider using -Filter instead of -Include unless you need to includ multiple items.  For something like *.txt, -Filter can be significantly faster.  Or you could always add both.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
# nouns should be singular unless results are guaranteed to be plural.
# arguments have been changed to match cmdlet parameter types
Function Get-Directory([string[]]$path, [string[]]$include, [switch]$recurse) 
{ 
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include $include -Recurse:$recurse | `
         Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } 
}
```

This works because -Recurse:$false is the same has not having -Recurse at all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the extra mile of fixing the function name and parameter declarations. Learnt more than I asked.

Answer (score 4):

In PowerShell 3.0, it is baked in with `-File` `-Directory` switches:

```
dir -Directory #List only directories
dir -File #List only files
```

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Directory

Answer (score 2):

The answer Oisin gives is spot on.  I just wanted to add that this is skirting close to wanting to be a proxy function.  If you have the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) 2.0 installed, you already have this proxy function.  You have to enable it (it is disabled by default).  Just edit the Pscx.UserPreferences.ps1 file and change this line so it is set to $true as shown below:

```
GetChildItem = $true # Adds ContainerOnly and LeafOnly parameters 
                     # but doesn't handle dynamic params yet.
```

Note the limitation regarding dynamic parameters.  Now when you import PSCX do it like so:

```
Import-Module Pscx -Arg [path to Pscx.UserPreferences.ps1]
```

Now you can do this:

```
Get-ChildItem . -r Bin -ContainerOnly
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder of PowerShell Community Extensions. I could have used it as a reference. As this is part of a build process I'll stick with what I've got because I don't want to add another dependency.