# clean up bin obj folders for C# visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to clean up the bin/ and obj/ folders of all dependencies and application? I am working on changing some of the references, and I have to manually clean up this from the drive for each dependency. It is a painful process. Is there an option in Visual Studio 2010 that will clean up these folders before I build solution. The Clean Solution does not clean the copied dlls, but only cleans the application executables.

Comment: Why not just delete all the bin/obj folders? The relevant binaries should built/copied when you rebuild.

Comment: I mean thats what I said is a painful process. Consider a solution with 25 dependencies in different locations. Its a painful process to clean up bin/ and obj/ for each one of them, before I rebuild all. Also prone to error. Would be nice to have a command that does that

Comment: I guess I'm at a loss what you actually mean, in the time it takes to make this comment you could search the root folder for "bin or obj" and delete the folders and then rebuild the solution. Of course this is a very narrow view of the problem because I don't understand the dependency linking, can you elaborate?

Comment: Why do you need to do anything? If you "Rebuild the Solution" it will automatically delete everything out of Debug or Release folder and put in what is required to run the application.

Comment: Ok, so the project I am working on has many dependencies. Now, I made changes to references of the project and its depedencies, such as changing "Copy Local" properties and moving to shared location, etc. Now I want to clean up the bins and rebuild solution. If I don't clean up, the old referenced dlls stay there. Of course I can search for all bin/ and obj/ in the root and clean them all. But don't you think that is prone to error if there are many other applications?

Comment: @TyCobb when you rebuild, it doesn't delete the old referenced dlls that you no longer want.

Comment: @QuintinRobinson I agree with you. Select all files and delete. Anything we're missing?

Comment: Then use "Clean Solution" or create your own prebuild script to delete the folders. It really shouldn't be that big of a problem.

Comment: @user236215 I don't think it is prone to errors actually, depending on your project structure. I want to be able to provide you with an easy solution but outside of making a prebuild script I happen to think that just deleting the relevant folders is the most prudent. When you say "consider a project with 25 dependencies in different locations" do you mean 25 other projects in different locations with independent bin/obj folders that you also need to remove?

Comment: @QuintinRobinson yes. Because I am simultaneously changing them.

Comment: @user236215 Eeek, sounds painful =/. IMHO just make a library in windows that includes all the project folders and then use that library to search for the bin/obj folders and delete from there.

Comment: @QuintinRobinson yes thats why I thought a command in Visual Studio to  do a "deep clean" would have been useful. But I am using the pre build events in Visual Studio to set up something. THanks for your help

Comment: Clean Solution doesn't delete the bin and obj folders.  If there are items in those folders that aren't created by the build process, it leaves them there.

Answer (score 0):

import Get-Directory from: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270377/89584

```
Function Get-Directory([string[]]$path, [string[]]$include, [switch]$recurse) 
{ 
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include $include -Recurse:$recurse | `
         Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } 
}
```

then do:

```
Get-Directory -Path SOLUTION_DIR -Include obj,bin -Recurse \
| Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

where SOLUTION_DIR is wherever your solution root is.

You could probably turn this into a build event fairly easily.